# Layout is displayed in wrong direction in React Native (using Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, right-to-left

I have developed an app in React native, using Expo.. when I tested it out on the android emulator and on my phone everything was fine layout-wise.. however, a problem occurred when I gave the APK to some other people to test it out for me.. The layout was reversed for RTL phones.. I wrote these 2 lines in the constructor of `App.js` (the root file) to solve the problem

```
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);  
I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
```

However this solution works only on the second time the app is launched, and it does not work the first time the app is launched (which is leaving quite a bad impression).. I read solutions to use an npm package called **RNRestart** but it requires linking and expo does not support linking, so I was left using the Expo function `Util.reload()` on first boot, however, it did not help these people and their apps layout is still shown in reverse the first time they use it..

as a quick fix, we have decided to show an error message that prompts the user to exit the app and re-enter if this is the first time the app loads (which is quite a nasty solution)

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: @hongdevelop in the constructor of `App.js`, as mentioned in my original post

Answer (score 4):

restart your app in case you detect I18nManager.isRTL

How to do it?

install:

```
npm i fiction-expo-restart
```

in app.js
import:

```
import {Restart} from 'fiction-expo-restart';
```

and

```
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';
```

then in componentDidMount() function:

```
componentDidMount()
{
  if(I18nManager.isRTL) 
  {
    I18nManager.allowRTL(false);  
    I18nManager.forceRTL(false); 
    Restart();
  }
}
```

library I used can be found here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fiction-expo-restart

Comment: You can use expo-updates now: 
import { reloadAsync } from 'expo-updates';
reloadAsync()

Answer (score 0):

**You can add code in AndroidManifest.xml to disable Rtl by default and you do not have to restart app**

```
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml -->
<application
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    ....
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10204) also

Comment: I am familiar with this solution, however, expo does not have an option edit the manifest or editing native code.. so yeah.. wish I could that but I can’t do it in expo

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use both. If you use only one, it works the same. You can set it outside of the `App` class. Here is an example of a test.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, I18nManager, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
I18nManager.allowRTL(false); 

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    isRTL: I18nManager.isRTL,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.directionBox}>
          <Text style={styles.directionText}>
            {this.state.isRTL ? 'Right-to-Left' : 'Left-to-Right'}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.flexDirectionRow}>
          <Text style={styles.switchRowTextView}>
            forceRTL
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.switchRowSwitchView}>
            <Switch
              onValueChange={this._onDirectionChange}
              style={styles.rightAlignStyle}
              value={this.state.isRTL}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _onDirectionChange = () => {
    I18nManager.forceRTL(!this.state.isRTL);
    this.setState({ isRTL: !this.state.isRTL });
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  directionBox: {
    backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'black',
  },
  directionText: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },

  flexDirectionRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  switchRowTextView: {
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  switchRowSwitchView: {
    flex: 3,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For expo at the time of this answer Feb. 2023, this code works:

First install this package:
`npm install expo-updates`

import it like this:
`import * as Updates from "expo-updates";`

To restart:
`Updates.reloadAsync();`